# Having issue with character encoding while processing a text

Tags: python, encoding, gensim

I am trying to process a large corpus but in preprocess_string( ) it returns an error shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/Projects/docs_handler/data_preprocessing.py", line 60, in <module> for temp in batch(iterator,1000): File "D:/Projects/docs_handler/data_preprocessing.py", line 30, in batch for item in iterable: File "D:/Projects/docs_handler/data_preprocessing.py", line 23, in iter_tokenized_documents document = preprocess_string(open(os.path.join(root, file)).read().strip(),filters=CUSTOM_FILTERS) File "C:\Users\koradg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16144: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

```
Versions
Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
NumPy 1.17.0
SciPy 1.3.0
gensim 3.8.0
FAST_VERSION 0
```

---

```
def iter_tokenized_documents(input_directory):
    """Iterate over all documents, yielding a document (=list of utf8 tokens) at a time."""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_directory):
        for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.txt'), files):
            document = preprocess_string(open(os.path.join(root, file)).read().strip(),filters=CUSTOM_FILTERS)
            if(len(document)):
                yield document
```

How to run it without any error?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to read your error stack without proper newline formatting, but also, from a quick glance, it's not clear there's any `gensim` code involved in the error. You should try to whittle the code down to a minimal example to trigger the error, and also share the file (or lines-of-file) needed to trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question you are having encoding error.
Just use **encoding='utf-8'** in Open file.
If that charter is not important use this **errors="ignore"** in Open file.

Answer (score 1):

```py
open(os.path.join(root, file))
```

this is your issue: if opening files in text mode (the default) and not providing an encoding (also the default), Python will use `sys.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

That's rarely a good idea, but it's especially bad on Windows where it's more likely than not the "preferred encoding" is completely outdated and useless (e.g. CP850).

So to solve your issue, depending on your exact needs:

- explicitly provide whatever encoding your data files are in (likely UTF8 if they're text from later than the 90s)
- open your files in *binary mode* to bypass the entire issue (and get `bytes` as output rather than `str`)

Also a few additional nitpicks:

> yielding a document (=list of utf8 tokens)

1. There's no such thing as "utf8 tokens", and it's unclear whether you mean *utf8 code units* (in which case you really want to open the files in binary mode) or codepoints (text mode).
2. bytes and strings are sequences but they're not quite *lists*, it's risky to call them as such